# Puppet-Master / Puppet-Agent Deployment fails due to the puppet modules metadata.json file permissions

Tags: puppet, centos6.5

I am using the ***Puppet Master / Puppet Agent*** deployment in ***CentOS 6.5 64bits***.

My problem is about doing the request from Puppet Agent in order to start the puppet modules's installation. When I execute the following commandline from Puppet-Agent:

```
puppet agent --server <internal-puppet-server-hostname> --test
```

> The ouput result is:

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/modules/yum/metadata.json
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://<internal-puppet-server-hostname>/pluginfacts: Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/modules/yum/metadata.json
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/modules/yum/metadata.json
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://<internal-puppet-server-hostname>/plugins: Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/modules/yum/metadata.json
Info: Caching catalog for <internal-puppet-agent-hostname>
Info: Applying configuration version '1440623253'
```

About the returned response, I show that the problem occurs because of the permissions of ***metadata.json***'s file. Then, I've checked the permissions of ***metadata.json***:

```
-r--------.  1 root root   539 2015-08-18 14:19 metadata.json
```

Some ideas about error occurs? Thanks.

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/puppet-community/puppet-collectd/issues/91) in puppet repository, but in their case the puppet version was 3.4.3 but I have 3.8.2 version...